# Mostrar preview de imagen antes de subirla en ASP

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Como puedo ver un preview de una imagen antes de subirla con el control

Algo así, pero con el control de ASP.NET
https://codepen.io/dyogophoenix/pen/QGNwRq

Answer (score 0):

A mi se me ocurre que puedes utilizar el ejemplo para mostrar la imagen en el lado del cliente (tal cual aparece en el ejemplo), que siempre queda muy bien, y luego subirlo a tu lado de servidor en ASP. Para ello puedes acceder al contenido de la imagen directamente haciendo algo como `document.getElementById("preview")`.